# Xpath following the for the next thumbnail - optimized solution? (for selenium automated solution)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

At demo [store](http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=3&controller=category) we have a list of thumbnail as given below :

```html
<ul class="product_list grid row">
  <li class="ajax_block_product....">
    <div class="product-container">
    <!-- at this level ist the thumbnail number 1 -->
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="ajax_block_product....">
    <div class="product-container">
    <!-- at this level ist the thumbnail number 2 -->
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="ajax_block_product....">
    <div class="product-container">
    <!-- at this level ist the thumbnail number 3 -->
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can navigate through thumbnails using the xpath mentioned below:

thumbnail number 1 = `//div[@class="product-container"]`

thumbnail number 2 = `//div[@class="product-container"]/following::div[@class="product-container"][1]`

thumbnail number 3 = `//div[@class="product-container"]/following::div[@class="product-container"][1]/following::div[@class="product-container"][1]`

Through, above xpath are working fine for me but not an optimized solution.

**Update 1:** The objective is leave the xpath in a closed "form" at web page object library, for using by automated tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the thumbnails in a list and then navigate through. Use below CSS selector for the same. Not sure which language you are using. I write this using Java.

```
List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.product-container"));
for(WebElement product : products){

    String productName = product.findElement(By.cssSelector(".product-name")).getText();
    String productPrice = product.findElement(By.cssSelector(".right-block .price")).getText();
    ...

}
```

OR using the xpath mentioned by you.

```
List<WebElement> allThumbnails = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-container']"));
for(WebElement thumbnails:allThumbnails){

    String productName = product.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@class='product-name']")).getText();
    String productPrice = product.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='right-block']//span[@class='price product-price']")).getText();
    ...
}
```

**UPDATED**

As per your comment if it is require to mentioned fix element in your xpath then using indexes would be the right approach.

there are total 7 product present on the page you shared the URL and xpath so you can write it like-

thumbnail number 1  = `//ul[@class='product_list grid row']/li[1]`

thumbnail number 2  = `//ul[@class='product_list grid row']/li[2]`

...

thumbnail number 7  = `//ul[@class='product_list grid row']/li[7]`

Comment: Hello thanks for the contribution. This solution is not possible because I have to leave xpath in an object library in a final version, so xpath must be in a "closed form". :-/

Comment: Hi. Closed form is a unique Xpath that identifies the object as is. For example if you put  the example I put in topic for thumbnail number 2 at your Browser Dev tools they automatic highlight the target. I hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

If all the products share the same class you can just have Selenium pick up all matching elements, as opposed to explicitly stating one after the other like you're currently trying.

You've not said what language you're using, but here's what it'd look like in C#:

```
// Setup your web driver...

var thumbnails = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class=\"product-container\"]"));
foreach (var thumbnail in thumbnails)
{
    // Do work
}
```

Or

```
for(int i = 0; i < thumbnails.Count; i++)
{
    // Do work by index
}
```

Note the plural `FindElements`, it returns a collection of all matching elements. Selenium does a fairly good job of matching methods across languages so that should point you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Hello thanks for the contribution. This solution is not possible because I have to leave xpath in an object library in a final version, so xpath must be in a "closed form".

Comment: If you were to call `FindElements` that returns a collection of all the thumbnails, which you can then refrence by index, so thumbnail 2 would be `ThumbColl[1]` for example. Stating the xpath explicitly in this "closed form" goes against the point of automation; it won't be a "solution that fits all" because you're referencing only the items on that specific page. What if the next product page has a different amount of items?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to elaborate on my comment, hopefully that explains what I mean.

Comment: sorry for not being able to make me understand. I will try another way. We have a robot, which has a selenium engine inside for the UI tests. However, we cannot invoke selenium functions (directly or indirectly). When mapping objects to Objects Iibrary we can only supply a "final" xpath that was consumed as is. As I said in the topic I already have the 3 xpaths but I wanted to understand if there is a more optimized code (mainly for the 2 and 3 thumbnail).